# How to go to "Home-page" in iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have `UIViewController` and `UITabBarController`. 
`UIViewController` contain 5 buttons and `UITabBarController` has 5 Tabs.

By tapping first button app shows `TabBarController` with the first selected tab, second - `TabBarController` with the second tab and so on...

To prepare this I have used `Modal-segue` for every button.

Everything works well.

Now I need to create "Home" button (may be programmatically) on `TabBarController`'s `UINavigationBar`, which will execute "Go home view" action.

**Edited with more details**

{see the screenshot below}

1. Initial UIViewController
2. UITabBarController
3. NavigationControllers
4. UIViewControllers

There are TWO modal-segues between **1** and **2** (two buttons - two segues)

In my **prepareForSegue** in UIViewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *d = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"s1"]) {
        d.initialTab = 0;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"s2"]) {
        d.initialTab = 1;
    }
}
```

In my **viewDidLoad** in UITabBarController:

```
TabController *mainTabController = (TabController *)self;
    AppDelegate *d = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [mainTabController setSelectedIndex:d.initialTab];
```

This is works!

But I need to go back to home-page. So if there is a NavigationController after TabBarController I would like to create a button in NavigationBar.

[image]

Comment: which is your home screen ??

Comment: add some code,explain your problem clearly.

Comment: have you tried `[self.parentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` ?

Comment: @Panu_Parekh: this isn't work ((

Comment: if you will put navigation controller at the beginning and set your firstview[with buttons] as a root view controller and hide your navigation bar in that view then it'll be done using what i have said before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take a one **Navigation Controller** as a parent.

Then, add your Startup View as a root view of it.

[image: Application Flow Suggestion]

On your main view controller page,

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

So, it will hide your main navigation. So no need to worry for this internal navigation flow.

And for internal navigation, you have already taken different navigation controllers.

By using code:

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

you'll be at root of the application and it will poped out all view controller which were stacked in application.

Hopefully, you'll understand flow & will apply if you feel good.

Enjoy Coding.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! But what about button? I have created BarButtonItem at my NavigationBar on the 4th view and wrote 

`[self.parentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

don't work ((

Comment: What did you mean by "add your Startup View as a root view of it"?

Comment: You add one navigation control first. then add you view controller as root of the navigation controller.

Comment: Then only, [self.parentViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; will work. Beacuse it'll find first navigation controller as a parent controller.

Comment: I understand, but how to set my mainViewController as a root? [I'm still new in Xcode ))]

Comment: just take navigation controller, press control & drag from navigation controller to your main view controller. Then release mouse, and set as rootViewController. It'll become a root view of main navigation controller.

Comment: gr8. Pleasure to help you.. Enjoy Coding..:)