# How to hide the rightBarButtonItem when navigating from tabbar?

Tags: ios

How I hide the rightBarButtonItem of a navigation controller when I want to navigate from tab-bar instead of Navigation Controller.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825066/how-to-disable-the-edit-button-that-appears-in-the-more-section-of-a-uitabbarcon

Comment: this post is related to enable the button, not to hide

Comment: Please add some code in your question.

Comment: if(self.parentViewController == self.navigationController )
{
        UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 

      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(Done)];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    }

if(self.parentViewController == self.tabBarController ){

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

             }

Comment: The top answer shows setting the button to nil, so it disables it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Hide the right button:

```
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

And to show it:

If you setup the right button in your view controller by assigning it to self.editButtonItem then simply assign it again in order to show it:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

Comment: How hide one of two rightBarButtonItem ? `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems[index] = nil ;`  don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just write this line in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear of the class in which you want to hide the right bar button

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Comment: if(self.parentViewController == self.navigationController )
{
        UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 

      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(Done)];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
    }

if(self.parentViewController == self.tabBarController ){

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

             }

Comment: First you have navigation controller and then you have tabbar controller. Right?

Comment: yes I have two way navigation in my project....I want hide the done button when user tab on tabbar...mean when tabbar open the navigationbar will be plain having no button on it

Comment: pls refer this question to set navigation controller and then tabbar.It'll help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377764/how-to-go-to-home-page-in-ios-app/15380682#15380682