# Change push-segue or its animation style

Tags: ios, animation, segue

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377764/how-to-go-to-home-page-in-ios-app) is my question about push-segue and go to "Home page" in iOS app.

Everything works, but push-segue have only one animation type "from right to left". In iPad app it is not beautiful. So, how could I change animation type, for example, to "fade"?

Or may be there is other way to prepare what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Starting iOS 7, you can use animated transitioning to customize. You can watch WWDC 2013 session 218 Custom Transitions Using View Controllers for more details